# How does one install EOS with NPM?

Tags: docker, installation

How does one install eos using npm, without going the route of docker image install? In other words, is there a workaround for installing without using the following docker command: `docker pull eosio/eos-dev`?

Comment: are you just looking for an alternative to docker or an alternative way to install and still use docker?

Comment: is there an alternative to docker install,

Comment: @user2243 If the answer below solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't install eosio using npm.

If you're looking for an alternative way to install & run a development environment using Docker you can follow the instructions for [Docker-compose](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker) below. You can also choose a different build option altogether, I've added one below the Docker instructions:

> git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git --recursive  --depth 1
>
> cd eos/Docker
>
> docker build . -t eosio/eos
>
> The above will build off the
> most recent commit to the master branch by default. If you would like
> to target a specific branch/tag, you may use a build argument. For
> example, if you wished to generate a docker image based off of the
> v1.0.0 tag, you could do the following:
>
> docker build -t eosio/eos:v1.0.0 --build-arg branch=v1.0.0
>
> By default, the symbol in eosio.system is set to SYS. You can override
> this using the symbol argument while building the docker image.
>
> docker build -t eosio/eos --build-arg symbol=ABC
>
> Start nodeos docker container only
>
> docker run --name nodeos -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 -t
> eosio/eos nodeosd.sh -e arg1 arg2
>
> By default, all data is persisted in
> a docker volume. It can be deleted if the data is outdated or
> corrupted:
>
> $ docker inspect --format '{{ range .Mounts }}{{ .Name }} {{ end }}'
> nodeos
> fdc265730a4f697346fa8b078c176e315b959e79365fc9cbd11f090ea0cb5cbc
>
> $ docker volume rm fdc265730a4f697346fa8b078c176e315b959e79365fc9cbd11f090ea0cb5cbc
>
> Alternately, you can directly mount host directory into the container
>
> docker run --name nodeos -v /path-to-data-dir:/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir
> -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 -t eosio/eos nodeosd.sh -e arg1 arg2
>
> Get chain info
>
> curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_info
>
> Start both nodeos and keosd containers
>
> docker volume create --name=nodeos-data-volume
>
> docker volume create --name=keosd-data-volume
>
> docker-compose up -d

If you are looking for an alternative to Docker altogether there are several build options available with instructions on the [dev documentation site](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/install-nodeos)

After cloning the repo:

> Run the build script from the eos folder.
>
> cd eos
>
> ./eosio_build.sh
>
> After the script has completed, install EOSIO
>
> ./eosio_install.sh
>
> For ease of contract development, content can be installed in the
> /usr/local folder using the make install target. This step is run from
> the build folder. Adequate permission is required to install.
>
> cd build
>
> sudo make install